# SSRS Generate different table on each page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have built a report that has 2 sections populated based on a parameter. Once the parameter was chosen both sections populated correctly.

The sections are:

```
Title -> this is the parameter chosen from a dropdown
Department -> populated based on parameter
Division -> populated based on parameter
-------------------------------------------------------
System | Access -> table populated based on parameter
```

All the data is stored in one table; each Title has one Department, one Division, multiple Systems, Access.

I need to change the SSRS report to generate all the data at once without parameters, meaning it has to loop through each Title and populate the rest of the information, generating different tables on every page.  Is this even possible in SSRS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the query does return all the information, but it populates the first section with the first Title/Depart/Division and then it generates one large table. I need it to loop through the Titles and generate one page with one table for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If necessary modify your query such that it returns all the rows for all the titles. Then:

1. Create a `List` which you group by the Title/Department/Division and show the Title/Department/Division using `TextBox`s.
2. Create a `Table` within your `List` and reference the same dataset and it will automatically display the rows associated with the current group being displayed in the `List`.